# Node.js child process, access process object in event handle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

So I have an array of child processes in my NodeJs application. Now I have

```
cp_array[i].process.on("exit",exithandle(code,signal));
```

On each of them.
The problem is I want to be able to access the process object of the process that exited in the exithandle. So if I'd put like cp_array[i].process.name="example" I'd be able to access my "example" string with process.name within the exithandle function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `cp_array[i].process` through the `this` keyword:

```
function exithandle(code, signal) {
    var process = this;
    return function() {
        // Whatever
    };
}
```